# no route matches controller (Rails 3)

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3

I'm pretty new to RoR, please help me identify where I am wrong

I get the following error

```
Routing Error
No route matches {:controller=>"groups"}
Try running rake routes for more information on available routes
```

when trying to render the following view

```
<li><%= link_to 'My groups', user_groups_path %></li>
<li><%= link_to 'New group', new_user_group_path %></li>
```

and here is 'routes.rb' and rake routes output

```
devise_for :users 
resources :users do |user|
  resources :groups do |group| 
    resources :people do |person|
    end
  end
end
              new_user_session GET    /users/sign_in(.:format)                                                                 devise/sessions#new
                  user_session POST   /users/sign_in(.:format)                                                                 devise/sessions#create
          destroy_user_session GET    /users/sign_out(.:format)                                                                devise/sessions#destroy
                 user_password POST   /users/password(.:format)                                                                devise/passwords#create
             new_user_password GET    /users/password/new(.:format)                                                            devise/passwords#new
            edit_user_password GET    /users/password/edit(.:format)                                                           devise/passwords#edit
                               PUT    /users/password(.:format)                                                                devise/passwords#update
      cancel_user_registration GET    /users/cancel(.:format)                                                                  devise/registrations#cancel
             user_registration POST   /users(.:format)                                                                         devise/registrations#create
         new_user_registration GET    /users/sign_up(.:format)                                                                 devise/registrations#new
        edit_user_registration GET    /users/edit(.:format)                                                                    devise/registrations#edit
                               PUT    /users(.:format)                                                                         devise/registrations#update
                               DELETE /users(.:format)                                                                         devise/registrations#destroy
       user_group_people GET    /users/:user_id/groups/:group_id/people(.:format)                            people#index
                               POST   /users/:user_id/groups/:group_id/people(.:format)                            people#create
   new_user_group_person GET    /users/:user_id/groups/:group_id/people/new(.:format)                        people#new
  edit_user_group_person GET    /users/:user_id/groups/:group_id/people/:id/edit(.:format)                   people#edit
       user_group_person GET    /users/:user_id/groups/:group_id/people/:id(.:format)                        people#show
                               PUT    /users/:user_id/groups/:group_id/people/:id(.:format)                        people#update
                               DELETE /users/:user_id/groups/:group_id/people/:id(.:format)                        people#destroy
             groups GET    /users/:user_id/groups(.:format)                                                   groups#index
                               POST   /users/:user_id/groups(.:format)                                                   groups#create
          new_user_group GET    /users/:user_id/groups/new(.:format)                                               groups#new
         edit_user_group GET    /users/:user_id/groups/:id/edit(.:format)                                          groups#edit
              user_group GET    /users/:user_id/groups/:id(.:format)                                               groups#show
                               PUT    /users/:user_id/groups/:id(.:format)                                               groups#update
                               DELETE /users/:user_id/groups/:id(.:format)                                               groups#destroy
                         users GET    /users(.:format)                                                                         users#index
                               POST   /users(.:format)                                                                         users#create
                      new_user GET    /users/new(.:format)                                                                     users#new
                     edit_user GET    /users/:id/edit(.:format)                                                                users#edit
                          user GET    /users/:id(.:format)                                                                     users#show
                               PUT    /users/:id(.:format)                                                                     users#update
                               DELETE /users/:id(.:format)                                                                         users#destroy
```

here is 'model.rb'

```
class User < ActiveRecord::Base
has_many :groups

class Group < ActiveRecord::Base
belongs_to :user
has_many :people
```

please help me figure out how to fix the problem

many thanks.

UPD

here is solution, it works
I made all changes suggested by @Abibullah and two changes in controllers

view:

```
<li><%= link_to 'My groups', user_groups_path(current_user) %></li>
<li><%= link_to 'New group', new_user_group_path(current_user) %></li>
```

routes.rb

```
resources :users do |user|
    resources :groups do |group| 
      resources :people 
    end
end
```

devise_for :users

GroupsController.rb:

```
def index
@user = current_user
@user.groups = Group.all
```

was:
    def index
        @user = current_user
        @groups = Group.all
    end

UsersController.rb

```
class Devise::UsersController < DeviseController
   def show
   end
end
```

Comment: Do U have GroupsController?

Comment: I do. It was generated by Rails when I generated groups scaffold.
No changes were made there/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To Create a nested Group Inside User, U need to pass the user_id inside which U are Creating the Group.

For Ex: If I have user1

Then I will use the routes as this:

`link_to 'My groups', user_groups_path(user1)`

OR

`link_to 'My groups', user_groups_path(user1.id)`

AND

`link_to 'My Group', new_user_group_path(user1)`

OR

`link_to 'My Group', new_user_group_path(user1.id)`

This is to tell that, To which User you are creating the Group.

If U want to access any specific Group, say for ex: grp1

then My url will be

`link_to 'My Group', user_group_path(user1, grp1)`

THis is a good refrence for routing.

http://guides.rubyonrails.org/routing.html

Comment: Have tried `link_to 'My Group', new_user_group_path(current_user)` (according to my use case). And still got the same problem. Like this: `No route matches {:action=>"show", :controller=>"groups", :user_id=>#<User id: 34, email: "zzzzzz" ... etc`

Comment: This may sound crazy, In your routes. Can U move device after the block of routes that you have wriiten.

Comment: Just tried. Nothing changes :( Why 'crazy'? I also suppose that problem is in my `routes.rb`, but I don't know what to change there.

Comment: Just Noticed One Thing.  Change the new path code to like this.`link_to 'My Group', new_user_group_path(current_user.id)`. I feel like the routes are correct.

Comment: Have tried. Result is the same: `No route matches {:action=>"show", :controller=>"groups", :user_id=>34}`

Comment: Good rendering is when I made `<li><%= link_to 'My groups', url_for([current_user, @groups]) %></li>
<li><%= link_to 'New group', new_user_group_path(current_user.id) %></li>` but both links don't work, hmm.

Comment: I solved the problem somehow (frankly speaking, I cannot figure out how). Thank you so much for your help.

Comment: Can U update the solution @maria. Wat did u do. So that I can try understand.

Comment: Yes, just have updated the initial post. Appreciate your help.

Answer (score 0):

I think it's obvious. You've got a typo in your

```
<li><%= link_to 'My groups', user_groups_path %></li>
```

link. The path should be `user_group_path` (without the 's') as shown in your `rake routes` output, instead of the one you've written in your link.

Comment: I made the change as you suggest. A now it says 'No route matches {:action=>"new", :controller=>"groups"}'.

Comment: Addition to the previos comment. It sayd `No route matches {:action=>"show", :controller=>"groups"}`. (not `new`)

I also tried to remove this `<li><%= link_to 'My groups', user_group_path %></li>` from the view.
So only `<li><%= link_to 'New group', new_user_group_path %></li>` remained. And then it said that `No route matches {:action=>"new", :controller=>"groups"}`.

So, problem still exists...